# Divi Woocoommerce Shop speed issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, divi

I am currently trying to speed up a Wordpress webshop using the Divi Theme in combination with the Plugins WooCommerce & BodyCommerce.
The usage of this plugins is lowering the speed of the site. The current loading times are 5-10 seconds.  After deactivating the Plugins the site speed increases massively.

I already tried to use some client-side caching (WPRocket) as well as serverside caching. Both speeded up the page a little bit but not on a level that is suitable for our usecase.

Are there any suggestions regarding speeding up this plugins?

Comment: You should do some digging/debugging to narrow down the where and what the cause is instead of just adding more plugins and complexity.

Comment: Can you recommend any tools debugging speed issues on Wordpress/WooCommerce sites?

Comment: Hi. I also have the same problem. did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the Query Monitor plugin and contact the support of those plugins. Also: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/divi-speed-optimization